# Osirix database errors

Tags: database, macos

I am trying to use Osirix 5.8.5 on Mac El Capitan OS 10.11.3 and when I try and load Osirix I get an error message:

> OsiriX Database
>   Osiris cannot understand the model of current saved database... The database index will be deleted and reconstructed (no images are lost).

I am given 2 options --> Quit or OK

However when I click on OK the message keeps repeating and I cannot access the program. Thus I only quit. Does anyone have a solution for this problem please!!

Comment: Did you ever have an Osirix database on your machine before this version?  If so, is there any valuable data in it?  Do you know where the data is stored?  Does this page about [OsiriX local database](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Online_OsiriX_Documentation/Managing_your_local_OsiriX_database) help at all?

Comment: I had installed version 7.0.3 but deleted it can changed to 5.8.5 so I could use a specific plug in I was given. There was no database prior

Comment: Going back two main versions is a very retrograde step. I assume there's a very good reason for doing that, rather than the other people upgrading to a more modern version.

Comment: It is because the newer versions of OsiriX are not as plugin friendly. Tried the link you sent but cannot seem to solve the problem as I cannot get back this error message to even access the programme.

Comment: I've not used the product (I'm just using Google) so I can't help much more.  The page mentions some files that can be deleted safely.  If your database was created (touched) by the 7.0.x version, then it is entirely plausible that the newly installed 5.8.x version won't be able to understand everything.  To get going, I'd probably move the "OsiriX Data" folder in your Documents folder to 'OsiriX Data 7.0.3' or something like that, and then try again with the older version.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue - trying to use v5.7 after using v7. I tried uninstalling, deleting all relevant files and reinstalling but to no avail!

After battling with it for a while, I deleted the 'OsiriX Data' folder from my Documents folder. I then copied the Osirix Data folder from another mac (that is running v5.7 fine) and Osirix v5.7 is now working fine again. Hope this helps if you haven't already solved the issue!

Answer (score 0):

1. Quit OsiriX
2. Rename your "OsiriX Data" folder to "OsiriX Data 2"
3. Relaunch OsiriX : your database is now empty (in the background, OsiriX created a new and empty "OsiriX Data" folder)
4. Quit OsiriX
5. Move your "OsiriX Data 2" folder into "OsiriX Data/INCOMING.noindex/"
6. Relaunch OsiriX: your images will be re-indexed into the new database